# error: no match for 'operator>>' (operand types are 'QDataStream' and 'Unit*')

Tags: c++, qt

I'm trying to define the operators >> and << for a custom class called Unit, and I need to store a pointer.

here is how I define the functions

```
QDataStream &operator<<(QDataStream &out, const Unit *unit)
{
   out << unit->value();
   return out;
}

QDataStream &operator>>(QDataStream &in, Unit *unit)
{
   double value;
   in >> value;
   unit->setUserValue(value);
   return in;
}

void Unit::setUserValue(const qreal userValue)
{
    qDebug() << "setUserValue" <<  this->userValue() << userValue << QString::number(m_unit,2);
    if (this->userValue() == userValue)
        return;

    if(isDefault())
        m_value = userValue;
    else
        m_value = UnitManager::convertFrom(userValue,m_unit);

    qDebug() << "Value" <<  m_value;

    emit userValueChanged();
    setDirty(RamDirty);
}


   qRegisterMetaType<Unit*>();
    qRegisterMetaTypeStreamOperators<Unit *>();
```

I'm getting the following compilation error message

```
error: no match for 'operator>>' (operand types are 'QDataStream' and 'Unit*')
```

and also an error here

```
/usr/include/qt/QtCore/qmetatype.h:771: error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type 'quint8& {aka unsigned char&}' from an rvalue of type 'quint8 {aka unsigned char}'
         stream >> *static_cast<T*>(t);
                ^
```

I also defined the meta type

```
Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(Unit)
Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(Unit*)
```

The unit class interface

```
class Unit : public EraObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

    Q_PROPERTY(qreal userValue READ userValue WRITE setUserValue NOTIFY userValueChanged)
    Q_PROPERTY(quint32 category READ category CONSTANT)
    Q_PROPERTY(quint32 unit READ unit WRITE setup)

    Q_PROPERTY(QString symbol READ symbol NOTIFY symbolChanged)

    Q_ENUMS(CategoryId)
    Q_ENUMS(UnitId)

public:
   Unit(const Unit &other);
    Unit(int unit = Default, QObject *parent = 0);
    ~Unit() {}

    enum CategoryId {
        NoneCategory,
        TemperatureCategory,
        PressureCategory,

        CountCategory
    };

    enum UnitId {
        Default = NoneCategory,

        //Temperature
        Celsius = TemperatureCategory << 16, Fahrenheit,
        CountTemperature,

        //Pressure
        Pascal = PressureCategory << 16, Bar,
        CountPressure
    };
    qreal value() const { return m_value; }
    qreal userValue() const;

    quint32 category() const { return m_unit >> 16 ; }
    quint32 unit() const { return m_unit; }
    QString symbol() const;

    inline bool isDefault() const { return !(m_unit & 0xffff); }

    //Operators
    operator qreal() const;

    Unit& operator=(const qreal value);

    bool operator==(const Unit &other) const { return (m_value == other.m_value); }
    bool operator<(const Unit &other) const { return (m_value < other.m_value); }

    void loadFrom(Settings &set, bool ownGroup = true) override;
    void saveTo(Settings &set, bool ownGroup = true, bool force = false) override;

private:
    qreal m_value;
    quint32 m_unit;

signals:
    void userValueChanged();

    void unitChanged(int unit);

    void symbolChanged();

public slots:
    void changeUnit(const quint32 &unit);

    void setUserValue(const qreal userValue);
    void setup(quint32 unit, const QString name = QString(),QObject *parent = 0);

};

Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(Unit*)
```

**UPDATE:**

```
QDataStream &operator<<(QDataStream &out, const Unit *&unit)
{
   out << unit->value();
   return out;
}

QDataStream &operator>>(QDataStream &in, Unit *&unit)
{
   qreal value;
   in >> value;
   unit->setUserValue(value);
   return in;
}
```

In MAIN I define

```
qRegisterMetaType<Unit*>();
qRegisterMetaTypeStreamOperators<Unit *>();
```

in the header of Unit.h I define

```
Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(Unit*)
Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(Unit)
```

Comment: How do you use these functions? Can you please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us? And please include the complete and unedited error output in the body of the question.

Comment: I'm not using these functions they are defined for saving and loading a custom class in the qsettings

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I edited the question

Comment: Nice new account @andreahmed

Comment: @AlexisP. do you find the problem here ?

Comment: Show a sample, where you are using this operators. And show interface of your `Unit` class.

Comment: @SaZ I have provided the interface

Comment: @WernerHenze there is no semicolon for that macro

Comment: @SaZ when I define the following functions    qRegisterMetaType<Unit*>();
    qRegisterMetaTypeStreamOperators<Unit*>();
it gives me that error /usr/include/qt/QtCore/qmetatype.h:771: error: no match for 'operator>>' (operand types are 'QDataStream' and 'Unit*')
         stream >> *static_cast<T*>(t);
                ^

Comment: `qRegisterMetaType<Unit*>();` should be done in code scope. Not outside from methods / functions.

Comment: @SaZ I have put it into the main function, but still I get those errors

Comment: Your code is wrong. What will you do, if you will pass a nullptr to your operator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
QDataStream &operator<<(QDataStream &out, Unit *&unit);
```

You are trying to pass a pointer instead of a reference to pointer.

But anyway, it is a good practice to use copyable and self-constructable types for stream operators. Because you have a lot of potential errors with uninitialized pointers.

Comment: please take a look at my updated code in the post, still I get an error which is /usr/include/qt/QtCore/qmetatype.h:771: error: no match for 'operator>>' (operand types are 'QDataStream' and 'Unit')
         stream >> *static_cast<T*>(t);
                ^

Comment: @ahmedandre i forgot to remove const ;)